# Can't create element in Xml file with Php

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I'm working on some project and i have to save movie(id,title,genre) in a xml file using php.
when i create xml file and add information it works perfectly
I mean ,
file : php

```
$document_xml = new DomDocument("1.0","UTF-8");

$movie_dom = $document_xml->createElement("movie");
$id_dom = $document_xml->createElement("id",$id);
$title_dom = $document_xml->createElement("title",$title);
$genre_dom = $document_xml->createElement("genre",$genre);

$movie_dom->appendChild($id_dom);
$movie_dom->appendChild($title_dom);
$movie_dom->appendChild($genre_dom);

$document_xml->appendChild($movie_dom);
$document_xml->save("data.xml");
```

and i have 
file : data.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <movie>
     <id>1</id>
     <title>Iron man</title>
     <genre>Action</genre>
   </movie>
```

but when i modify the code like this 
file : php

```
$document_xml = new DomDocument();
$document_xml->load("data.xml");

$movie_dom = $document_xml->createElement("movie");
$id_dom = $document_xml->createElement("id",$id);
$title_dom = $document_xml->createElement("title",$title);
$genre_dom = $document_xml->createElement("genre",$genre);

$movie_dom->appendChild($id_dom);
$movie_dom->appendChild($title_dom);
$movie_dom->appendChild($genre_dom);

$document_xml->appendChild($movie_dom);
$document_xml->saveXML();
```

so that to have,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <movie>
      <id>1</id>
      <title>Iron man</title>
      <genre>Action</genre>
   </movie>
   <movie>
      <id>id</id>
      <title>some title</title>
      <genre>some genre</genre>
   </movie>
```

I have no error and there is no change in my xml file
I would like your help

Comment: You must have one, and only one root element in an XML file; you're trying to create two.... give yourself a '<movies>' root elemnt in your original file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, i change the structure of my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <movie>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>Iron man</title>
    <genre>Action</genre>
  </movie>
  <movie>
    <id>2</id>
    <title>La guerre des etoiles</title>
    <genre>adventure</genre>
  </movie>
  <movie>
    <id>3</id>
    <title>Jugement dernier</title>
    <genre>action</genre>
  </movie>
</data>
```

i change my php file like this

```
$document_xml = new DomDocument();
$document_xml->load("data.xml",LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
$document_xml->formatOutput = true;

$root = $document_xml->documentElement;

$movie_dom = $document_xml->createElement("movie");
$id_dom = $document_xml->createElement("id",$value);
$title_dom = $document_xml->createElement("title",$title);
$genre_dom = $document_xml->createElement("genre",$genre);

$movie_dom->appendChild($id_dom);
$movie_dom->appendChild($title_dom);
$movie_dom->appendChild($genre_dom);

$root->appendChild($movie_dom);
$document_xml->appendChild($root);
$document_xml->save("data.xml");
```

everything wworks perfectfly ...